# Call to malloc, unknown size

Tags: c

I am getting the current working directory with _getcwd. The function requires a pointer to the buffer, and the buffers size.

In my code I am using:

```
char *cwdBuf;
cwdBuf = malloc(100);
```

I don't know the size of the buffer needed, so I am reserving memory way to big than is needed. What I would like to do is use the correct amount of memory.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

What is your target platform? The [`getcwd()` documentation here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) makes two important points:

> As an extension to the POSIX.1-2001 standard, Linux (libc4, libc5, glibc) **getcwd() allocates the buffer dynamically using malloc() if buf is NULL on call**. In this case, the allocated buffer has the length size unless size is zero, when buf is allocated as big as necessary. It is possible (and, indeed, advisable) to free() the buffers if they have been obtained this way...
>
> ...The buf argument should be a pointer to an array at least PATH_MAX bytes long. getwd() does only return the first PATH_MAX bytes of the actual pathname.

Comment: Linux isn't all of the world ;-) The OpenGroup UNIX refs say, under `sysconf()`, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sysconf.html , that `PATH_MAX` may be so large that using it to allocate an array, `curwd[PATH_MAX]`, might not work (due to stack limits being smaller than `PATH_MAX`). Depending on your environment or ulimit settings, this could even apply on Linux, particularly in embedded.

Comment: @FrankH: indeed, that's why I asked what his target platform was :)

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a `MAX_PATH` macro defined which you can use. Also is there any reason not to just allocate on the stack?

Edit:

From the MSDN Docs:

```
#include <direct.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
   char* buffer;

   // Get the current working directory: 
   if( (buffer = _getcwd( NULL, 0 )) == NULL )
      perror( "_getcwd error" );
   else
   {
      printf( "%s \nLength: %d\n", buffer, strnlen(buffer) );
      free(buffer);
   }
}
```

So it looks like if you pass in NULL, it allocates a buffer for you.

Comment: @Paul: depends on the platform. For Win32 I think it's MAX_PATH.

Comment: @Nick: even Microsoft has the standard macro `PATH_MAX` defined in `<limits.h>` (it's 512 on WIN32). `MAX_PATH` is an MFC thing and should be avoided in the interest of portability.

Comment: @Paul: Hmm, no, `MAX_PATH` is a Windows API thing, not MFC. It may *also* be part of MFC, but only because MFC is a thin wrapper around the Win32 API. It's defined in `windows.h`.

Comment: @Cody: you're probably right - I use Windows as little as possible - but the bottom line is that the standard macro `PATH_MAX` is defined in `<limits.h>` even when using Visual Studio, whereas the Windows-specific macro `MAX_PATH` is Microsoft-only and should be avoided if you want to write portable code.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the current working directory is unknown as such but its upper limit can be asked for.

The correct way of allocating memory to use for `getcwd()` is by *querying* the system for the maximum length buffer required, via `pathconf(".", _PC_PATH_MAX);` before allocating the buffer and calling `getcwd()`.

The OpenGroup UNIX standard manpages document this [for `getcwd()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html) in the example code given. Quote:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
...
long size;
char *buf;
char *ptr;

size = pathconf(".", _PC_PATH_MAX);

if ((buf = (char *)malloc((size_t)size)) != NULL)
    ptr = getcwd(buf, (size_t)size);
...
```

Comment: Why would you need a pointer to getcwd? Isn't the current working directory stored in buf?

Comment: @Jack Harvin: refer to the doc that FrankH linked to. You need to check that return value. If `ptr == NULL` then the call to `getcwd()` failed (errno is set). On success `ptr == buf`.

Answer (score 0):

How about `realloc()` once you know the size of the result?